# Ubuntu 15.04 OpenStack Kilo Swift and Horizon Install

Tags: openstack

I've installed Ubuntu 15.04 and am in the process of installing OpenStack Kilo as described in [OpenStack Kilo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 15.04 – Single machine setup – Free and Open Source Software Knowledge Base](https://fosskb.wordpress.com/2015/04/18/installing-openstack-kilo-on-ubuntu-15-04-single-machine-setup/). The instructions include the installation of KeyStone, Glance, and Nova. I also want to install the Horizon dashboard and Swift. Could you send me a link for their installation?

Comment: Your response seems a bit odd.  Ubuntu is activitly promoting the deplyment of OpenStack on its Linux distribution (see https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/04/22/here-comes-kilo-15-05-containers-will-never-be-the-same-again/, http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2405036/canonicals-ubuntu-1504-sees-the-debut-of-openstack-kilo, https://fosskb.wordpress.com/2015/04/18/installing-openstack-kilo-on-ubuntu-15-04-single-machine-setup/. ).  It supports this by supplying OpenStack in it deb repository. So my request for a little help from you did not seem so "off topic".

Comment: Sorry for not checking your link first; close vote retracted.  (It's just that I personally never heard about these and a link to a wordpress blog instead of to an Ubuntu site and a reputation 1 user made me think you were a *recently migrated XP user asking how to install Windows software on Ubuntu*)  **;-)  My apologies!**

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's a very old question and possibly you have already installed and used Openstack Kilo but I'll still paste the resources for some users that may stumble upon this while wandering on Google:

1. [Complete documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/install-guide/install/apt/content/) for installation of all components on Ubuntu 14.04. No reason why it wouldn't work on Vivid. Did I tell 15.04 comes with a pre-installed version of Openstack Kilo? Yes you just install Ubuntu and access it using Horizon in a browser.
2. [This dude](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ecqs8-_xO54&index=7&list=PLPNBK2jcH43-O5vHoc7APsXbAjn88ykbt) isn't very talkative but if you aren't a linux noob, you could easily follow what he's doing, i.e. installing Openstack Kilo in a distributed environment on Ubuntu 15.04 server systems.